# Angular 6: Can't resolve all parameters for Component: (?)

Tags: angular

We've been on Angular v6.0.0-beta.3 for a long time, but recently we've tried upgrading to version 6.1.3.

I've been unable to upgrade using angular schematics as they don't seem to support external registries (we use Artifactory) so I've had to upgrade it manually so it's very possible I've messed something up.

Currently after upgrading I am getting this stacktrace:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for LoginComponent: (?).
at syntaxError (compiler.js:1016)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:10917)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:10810)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:10429)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (compiler.js:11013)
at compiler.js:11004
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentsFromProvider (compiler.js:11003)
at compiler.js:10976
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

LoginComponent injects the AuthService. If I put AuthService in the `provide` array property of the LoginComponent then it stops complaining about that error and gives me the same error for another component.
I've tried replacing ALL Injectable's with the new `providedIn: 'root'` configuration but it still doesn't work. I've tried cleaning npm cache and removing node_modules and still the same problem. I'm lost on what I've done wrong.

Running in AOT actually correctly launches the app, but then I get these stack traces when doing things with some components (I think material):

```
ERROR TypeError: a[getSymbolIterator(...)] is not a function
at areIterablesEqual (core.js:5492)
at devModeEqual (core.js:5421)
at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:7689)
at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:10552)
at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:10541)
at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:11144)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:11072)
at Object.updateDirectives (login.component.html:37)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:11061)
at checkNoChangesView (core.js:10440)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: LoginComponent constructor

```
constructor(
    private authService: AuthService) {
  }
```

AuthService class declaration

```
    @Injectable()
export class AuthService {
```

All my providers are provided in the AppModule.

Comment: please show the constructor of login component

Comment: sorry you need to show some of your code to let people identify your issues

Comment: Sorry. I updated my post

Answer (score 5):

Add `@Inject` decorator around AuthService instantiation in the LoginComponent

```js
constructor(
  @Inject(AuthService) private authService: AuthService) {
}
```

This helps compiler know that AuthService will be injected later.

Comment: But I shouldn't have to do that

Comment: Experiencing the same here. This helped me, but  I was doing this to successfully inject anything, even @angular/router.

Comment: That does sound odd @niCad, but without your full setup I cannot provide any helpful info. This should have been solved in the meantime though.
An explicit injection is only needed when you are loading services dynamically.

Comment: This worked for me, but **begs** what in the world would is going on that makes us have to do this (?)

Answer (score 0):

Put `AuthService` in the `providers` array of `AppModule`

Comment: Sorry I should have added that.

We already had all our providers in the AppModule providers array.
So I also tried adding `providedIn: 'root'` to all Injectables with the providers in the AppModule and with them removed from the AppModule. Still the same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can't resolve all parameters for
> AComponent

after I switched to a very old feature branch and updated the branch with the latest main branch changes.

I was confused because the component loaded properly a few months ago, and there have been no changes to the component.

Later, I found that restarting `ng serve` fixed the issue.